# Sorting HEX color swatch palette

Tags: flutter, colors, hex, color-palette

I have a list of colors and would like to sort them into a palette like [this](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/rwLPYe): `[https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/rwLPYe][1]`.

Is there a package for doing this or any piece of code that would help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [flutter palette package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_palette) has a number of options for palette manipulation.